# activeMQ queues slowed down by connection to broker?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Hello if 2 apps are communicating via sending to each others' JMS queue, but one of them has sporadic network slowness to the activeMQ broker will that slow down their queue-to-queue communication?

I've been ordered to add my app at location B, but we must keep our broker at location A. The network connection can be slow A <--> B. I've given B it's own little world including its own instance of the app it communicates most with. This is all via queue-to-queue, but will slowness to the jms broker at A slow it? The apps at B do very little with the broker once they start communicating queue-to-queue.

Comment: Unfortunately, no answers :( Pls add a comment if further clarification would help (or perhaps there is an obvious answer I missed). We know this: our tests show the 2 components running at site B exhibit no slowness, but not conclusive. We are not experts and can't really slow down the network at will, but we've tried. The 2 components at site B only use jms topics for about 1% of their messages. The rest is via their JMS queues. I hope this means network slowness to the broker has low impact. I'd love some comments from others, especially experts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand fully your questions. Do you want to mean:
"if my connection app <-> broker is slow, will it slow down my activeMQ queue?"
Well, both are not related. Slow connection to the broker means two things:

- The remote application in site A will take longer to dequeue messages (and hence acknowledge the messages). This means that you might have a case of slow consumer (you must protect against that, as if you have a high throughput, the data store might explode in size and reach the limits),
- The remote application in site A will take longer to en queue messages. Once the message is transmitted to the broker, the application in B will have no slowness to handle it.

At the end, I only foresee problems on the consumption from B to A, but you can protect yourself against that (see [Slow Consumer Handling](http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html)), and it will happen only if your connection is really slow and you have a high number of messages per second.
The broker is not going to be affected by a consumer having a slow connection otherwise